# How can I tell if a Java integer is null?

Tags: java, integer

Greetings,

I'm trying to validate whether my integer is null.  If it is, I need to prompt the user to enter a value.  My background is Perl, so my first attempt looks like this:

```
int startIn = Integer.parseInt (startField.getText());

if (startIn) { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
         "You must enter a number between 0-16.","Input Error",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                
}
```

This does not work, since Java is expecting boolean logic.

In Perl, I can use "exists" to check whether hash/array elements contain data with:

```
@items = ("one", "two", "three");
#@items = ();

if (exists($items[0])) {
    print "Something in \@items.\n";
}
else {
    print "Nothing in \@items!\n";
}
```

Is there a way to this in Java?  Thank you for your help!

Jeremiah

P.S. Perl [exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) info.

Comment: Is this really two separate questions? How does the use of a container have anything to do with the first example?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`parseInt()` is just going to throw an exception if the parsing can't complete successfully. You can instead use `Integers`, the corresponding object type, which makes things a little bit cleaner. So you probably want something closer to:

```
Integer s = null;

try { 
  s = Integer.valueOf(startField.getText());
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // ...
}

if (s != null) { ... }
```

*Beware* if you do decide to use `parseInt()`! `parseInt()` doesn't support good internationalization, so you have to jump through even more hoops:

```
try {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(locale);
    nf.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
    nf.setMaximumIntegerDigits(9); // Or whatever you'd like to max out at.

    // Start parsing from the beginning.
    ParsePosition p = new ParsePosition(0);

    int val = format.parse(str, p).intValue();
    if (p.getIndex() != str.length()) {
        // There's some stuff after all the digits are done being processed.
    }

    // Work with the processed value here.
} catch (java.text.ParseFormatException exc) {
    // Something blew up in the parsing.
}
```

Comment: Don't you just love a language that makes you catch so many exceptions just so you can ignore them :)

Comment: Frankly, I'd rather be forced to catch the exception rather than let it sit there uncaught and when my stack becomes huge have to find where I was an idiot a long time ago. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
Integer startIn = null;

try {
  startIn = Integer.valueOf(startField.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  .
  .
  .
}

if (startIn == null) {
  // Prompt for value...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`int`s are value types; they can never be `null`. Instead, if the parsing failed, `parseInt` will throw a `NumberFormatException` that you need to catch.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `exists` for a *SCALAR* in Perl, anyway. The Perl way is

```
defined( $x )
```

and the equivalent Java is

```
anInteger != null
```

Those are the equivalents.

```
exists $hash{key}
```

Is like the Java

```
map.containsKey( "key" )
```

From your example, I think you're looking for

if ( startIn != null ) { ...

Answer (score 2):

For me just using the Integer.toString() method works for me just fine.  You can convert it over if you just want to very if it is null.  Example below:

```
private void setCarColor(int redIn, int blueIn, int greenIn)
{
//Integer s = null;
if (Integer.toString(redIn) == null || Integer.toString(blueIn) == null ||     Integer.toString(greenIn) == null )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use "exists" on an integer in Perl, only on collections. Can you give an example of what you mean in Perl which matches your example in Java.

> Given an expression that specifies a hash element or array element, returns true if the specified element in the hash or array has ever been initialized, even if the corresponding value is undefined.

This indicates it only applies to hash or array elements!

Comment: I quite agree.  In my Perl example I used an array and then use exists to check whether an element in the array has content.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
Integer startIn = null;

// (optional below but a good practice, to prevent errors.)
boolean dontContinue = false;
try {
  Integer.parseInt (startField.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}

// in java = assigns a boolean in if statements oddly.
// Thus double equal must be used. So if startIn is null, display the message
if (startIn == null) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
       "You must enter a number between 0-16.","Input Error",
       JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                            
}

// (again optional)
if (dontContinue == true) {
  //Do-some-error-fix
}
```

Comment: (Too add source code you have to indent it with 4 spaces or one tab.)

Comment: @Kay : spaces or tab? that is the question :P